# AJAX call returns 404 on server, works locally

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, http-status-code-404

In my application I have a drop-down menu that lists various customers, and a second drop-down that will list the cities with which a given customer is associated. Selecting a customer should populate the second drop-down with the relevant list of locations. This happens by triggering an Ajax call to a method in the controller, which passes the name of the selected customer in variable "loc". The list of locations is obtained via an EF Core query.

This all works as expected on my local machine, but when running on our server it returns a 404 - Not Found error.

The Ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/[Controller]/GetLocations",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "text",
     data: { 'loc': loc },
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var listData = JSON.parse(data);
        resetLocationList();
        for (var listSize = 0; listSize < listData.length; listSize++) {
             $('#ffBankLocation').append('<option value="' + listData[listSize] + '">' + 
             listData[listSize] + '</option>');
        }

     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error caught: ');
        console.log(errorThrown);
     }
});
```

And the method in the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetLocations(string loc)
{
    var locations = await _repo.GetLocationsByName(loc);

    return Json(locations);
}
```

Finally, the URL as reported in the 404 error looks like this:

```
https://[URL]/[Controller]/GetLocations?loc=Some%20Location
```

Given that the URL value isn't being found, I doubt the settings after that have anything to do with the problem. The only thing I could think to change there is that the controller was contained in a sub-folder within the Controllers folder (Controllers/myFolder/Controller), but moving the controller to the main Controllers folder, no sub-folder in between, doesn't resolve the issue.

Any advice appreciated.

EDIT: To be clear about moving the controller, I did not move it from the main Controllers folder, I only moved it out of the sub-directory within the Controllers folder in which it was previously found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I needed to convert my drop-down list into an @Html.DropDownListFor object, and wrap it in a form object like so:

```
<form id="custNameForm" asp-controller="myController" asp-action="GetLocations" method="post">
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList((List<string>)ViewBag.custList), "Select Customer",
          new { @class="form-control text-center" })
</form>
```

Next, in my javascript file, I add the following "change" listener:

```
.on('change', '#CustName', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     GetLocations(e);
})
```

...which points to this jquery function:

```
function GetLocations(e) {
    var loc = $('#CustName option:selected').val();
    var noLoc = loc === '' || loc === 'Select Customer';

    if (!noLoc) {
        var form = $('#custNameForm');
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                'loc': loc
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                var listData = data;
                resetLocationList();
                for (var listSize = 0; listSize < listData.length; listSize++) {
                    $('#custLocation').append('<option value="' + listData[listSize] + '">' + listData[listSize] + '</option>');
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error caught: ');
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        parseXML('');
    }

    $('#custLocation').prop('disabled', noLoc);
}
```

... where "#custLocation is the ID of the dropdown to be populated with the list of customer locations.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove [HttpPost], and add attribute route

```
[Route("~/mycontroller/GetLocations")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetLocations(string loc)
```

if it is still not working try to change ajax to get

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/[Controller]/GetLocations?loc="+loc,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

and never ever move controllers from default Controllers folder

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but neither of these changes make a difference. Still getting a 404.

Comment: @Did you try to connect manually just typing url in the browser or using Postman? And  I would like to see your real url

Comment: Pasting the URL in a browser window gets me a "page cannot be found" error. As for showing the real URL, the place I work for is very security-oriented. No can do there. But if there's something you want to know about it, I can try to answer that for you.

Comment: @bmurrell30 I edited my answer, but I am not sure that it will help, since you don't understand what url should be.

Comment: "url" should be a reference to the method to be run in the controller, I'm clear on that.